# Implementing cache mechanism with retrofit 2 as like robospice + retrofit 1

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, retrofit2, robospice

I have been using [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)1 + [robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) to make API requests. You can check sample [here](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-retrofit). In this framework, I used to make request like this

```
getSpiceManager().execute(request, CACHE_KEY, DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE(CACHE_TIME), new ResponseListener());
```

Above statement will make sure that it will return the cached response for one minute from the time I requested(with the same cache key).But currently, robospice does not support retrofit v2. My Question is that is there any cache mechanism for retrofit v2 to implement like this. I googled for some time but I could not find what exactly I want.

Comment: have you checked okhttp cache mecahnism https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-activate-response-caching-etag-last-modified

Answer (score 0):

the proper way to cache responses in android is using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) (and it combines with Retrofit as well)
use the [cache](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#cache-okhttp3.Cache-) method :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(new Cache(cacheDir, MAX_SIZE))
            .build()

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
```